# No puedo responder a la 2nda pregunta. Parece que estoy usando de manera incorrecta el cin.ignore

Tags: c++

Cuando respondo la primera pregunta y uso espacios afecta el resultado de la 2nda pregunta por que se la salta. Cuando nada mas respondo sin espacios no se salta la segunda pregunta. parece que estoy usando de manera incorrecta el cin.ignore pero no me estoy dando cuenta de mi error. Alguien sabe como resolver este error para que yo pueda responder la primera y segunda pregunta sin errores? Esta es la unica duda que tengo la verdad, todo lo demas en mi codigo funciona. Solo quiero quiero poder responder el char variable sin que me afecte el string question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int rollDie();

int main()
{
    
    string question;
    char variable;
    
    do
    {

        cout << "Hello, I am the magic 8-ball! Ask me a question and I will give you an answer" << endl;
        cout << "Your question: ";

        
        cin >> question ;
        cin.ignore();

        cout << endl << endl;


        int roll = rollDie() % 5 + 1;

        if (roll == 5)
            cout << "Answer: It is certain " << endl;

        if (roll == 4)
            cout << "Answer: Reply hazy, Try Again " << endl;

        if (roll == 3)
            cout << "Answer: Don't count on it " << endl;

        if (roll == 2)
            cout << "Answer: Signs point to yes " << endl;

        if (roll == 1)
            cout << "Answer: My sources say no " << endl;

    



        cout << "Would you like to ask another question? Answer Y/N: ";
        cin >> variable;

    } while (variable == 'Y' || variable == 'y');


    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}




int rollDie()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand();
}
```

Comment: Lo mas facil seria usar `std::getline`, y leer por lineas,
asi te quedarias con la pregunta completa del usuario en caso
de que quieras hacer algo con ella en lugar de solo
descartarla. Pero si quieres, o tienes que (por ejemplo son
instrucciones de tarea), usar `std::cin::ignore`, tienes que
indicar cuantos caracteres quieres ignorar, y un delimitador.
En este caso entiendo que quieres ignorar hasta la siguiente
linea, asi que tu ignore tendria que ser:
`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),
'\n');`

Answer (score 0):

La definición de [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) es:

> ```
> basic_istream& ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() );
> ```

Por lo tanto, si no le pasas parámetro alguno estarás ignorando un máximo de UN carácter hasta llegar al final del flujo de datos. Supongo que lo que en realidad quieres es ignorar todos los caracteres, prueba esto:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```